# Can someone give a good analogy how to understand hyperledger fabric and all its components?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-sawtooth

I have tried to read the documentation and try to watch Youtube videos but everything is so new and overwhelming. I just need to understand basically what are those `certificates`, `msp`.

Please help me to understand .

Answer (score 1):

To know the certificate, you have to know how public key cryptography works and why we need certificate in public key cryptography, how an identity is considered as correct by using digital certificate. Hyperledger Fabric uses that technique to manage identities.

To know the MSP properly, you also need to know how public key cryptography works. Msp holds public information of different identities and provide access control mechanism into network.

You can read their [key concepts](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/key_concepts.html) but it's hard to understand for actual beginners.

Comment: Yes....its hard for me to understand it

Comment: Thanks... I'll start off by reading those

Comment: Please revise "public key cryptography, why we use public key cryptography in Blockchain, why we need certificate in public key cryptography,  how an identity is considered as correct by using digital certificate" before start key concepts.

Comment: Ok.. Thank you sir 